# How to move files from one directory to a nested directory using SSH?

Tags: shell, rename

I would like to know how to move all the files, not the folder or directory, to an existing folder or directory two levels down.

Comment: Why do you need to use SSH, and presumably scp and sftp? Can you not get a shell on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the find command.

```
find . -type f -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ../backup_dir ; mv ../backup_dir ./new/directory
```

Note that I've moved the files to a directory to one directory up, to prevent find from being stuck in a loop finding the new files that you're moving.  Then move the directory two levels down.

If you need only files in the current directory, you can use the command:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ../backup_dir
```

Comment: @uther - it's not always desirable to execute commands interactively, i.e. automated backup scripts on a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zsh available, this is pretty simple. The pattern `*` matches all files (including directories). To match only regular files, add the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `.`. Glob qualifiers are a zsh feature.

```
mv *(.) existing/subsubdirectory/
```

(Actually `*` skips files whose name begins with a `.` (“dot files”). This is probably not a concern here, but if you do need to move those as well, add a `D` inside the parentheses.)

Comment: Guys, I appreciate your efforts. I got more than I bargained for. Because I'm new to using PUTTY, I was able to copy the files, but will keep the code you offered to try later when I'm more comfortable. Thanks again for all the help.